# What are prerequisites for ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am a newbie to ROS. I am an Electronics undergrad and I have worked in the field of robotics for two years. But most of my experience is related to electronics. I have designed power supplies, motor drivers for robots; I have done some work on sensors, sensor interfacing and calibration. I have worked on ATmega series microcontrollers, Arduino, PIC & MSP430 . I have also done few projects using MATLAB and LabVIEW. I familiar with C/CPP programming but that is mostly in windows- visual studio and eclipse IDE. I also know basics of python. I have no experience with programming in Linux.

I am currently working on opencv.

I know my experience related to programming is very less, but I'm interested in implementing ROS on some custom robots. To do so, what are other things that I'll have to learn? Also what would you say about time that I will require to get started and complete a small project like simulating a simple robot using ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70651/what-are-prerequisites-for-ros?/) by [tSushant](https://answers.ros.org/users/5707/tsushant/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dPackard](https://answers.ros.org/users/4911/dpackard/) on 2013-08-02**:
You should learn some of the basics of linux/BASH before diving into the ROS tutorials (e.g. http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/). There's quite a learning curve for Linux+ROS if you're completely new to it, but with your background you should be up and running soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have mentioned every thing that is needed and in fact you know it.
All you need is to attempt to work on it.
to get confidence at initial stage you need to have an ROS supported robot and further you can manage it all for your own robot too.

---

Originally posted by [lifelonglearner](https://answers.ros.org/users/5249/lifelonglearner/) with karma: 205 on 2013-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1